# Refused to execute script

Tags: javascript

Refused to execute script from '/includes/codemirror/mode/java/java.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='includes/codemirror/codemirror.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/codemirror/codemirror.css">
<script type="application/javascript" src='includes/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src='includes/codemirror/mode/php/php.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src='includes/codemirror/mode/clike/clike.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src='includes/codemirror/mode/perl/perl.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src='includes/codemirror/mode/python/python.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src='includes/codemirror/mode/java/java.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src='includes/codemirror/mode/vb/vb.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src='includes/codemirror/mode/sql/sql.js'></script>
```

How can I fix the error? I cannot change server settings, haven't got access..

Comment: then disable strict mime checking?

Comment: Not possible. The server's broken. It's what must be fixed.

Comment: It's a security measure. As Stephen said, it should be fixed from the server.